# Coded UI test, CLR error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

The coded UI test was built with VS2010 and was open with VS2012. After being opened in VS2012 I opened it in VS2010 on another computer and then this error was shown:

> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected Message: The runtime has
>   encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x67ba416e,
>   on thread 0x1838. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a
>   bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user
>   code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for
>   COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Computer with VS2010 has .NET Framework 4.0 and the computer with VS2012 .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: You'll need to post this to connect.microsoft.com.  They will need your project to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the project in VS2012, check the project properties to ensure that the target framework is .NET 4.0.

> Project -> Properties -> Application tab -> Target framework

It could be that VS2012 incorrectly had the target framework as .NET 4.5? Try checking it anyway. If it is set to .NET 4.5 then change it to .NET 4.0. That should make VS2010 happy.

I can't help any more, but maybe this could be useful for you?

[How do I debug a .net Fatal Execution Engine Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205111/how-do-i-debug-a-net-fatal-execution-engine-error)

Comment: The target is .NET 4.0 same :(